# Is there a way to generate a matplotlib graph from two columns of a table?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code with an intermediate table that has the two columns I am interested in: Birth and Death. But when I go to plot it using matplotlib, it generates a blank graph. I have tried a similar approach to another task and it worked just fine.

code:

```
table = pop.with_column("Birth",sum(pop.column("BIRTHS")) / sum(pop.column("2015"))).with_column("Death", sum(pop.column("DEATHS")/sum(pop.column("2015"))))

plots.plot(table["Birth"], table["Death"])
plots.show()
```

Table:

[image]

Plot:

[image]

Comment: [`datascience`](http://data8.org/datascience/) is an unmaintained package for a Berkeley data science course. I do not recommend using this package. Use pandas. Always include all relevant code, like imports and data.

Comment: **[Don't Post Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/)**. Always provide a [mre], with **code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. It's likely the question will be down-voted and closed. You're discouraging assistance, as no one wants to retype data/code, and screenshots are often illegible. [edit] the question and **add text**. Plots are ok.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try printing your final data before plotting?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plots
import pandas as pd
#table = pop.with_column("Birth",sum(pop.column("BIRTHS")) / sum(pop.column("2015"))).with_column("Death", sum(pop.column("DEATHS")/sum(pop.column("2015"))))
d1=[{'Birth':10,'Death':12},{'Birth':11,'Death':14},{'Birth':14,'Death':16},{'Birth':16,'Death':18}]
table=pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
display(table)
plots.plot(table['Birth'], table['Death'])
plots.show()
```

output

[image: output]

Can you check your data in the **table** ?

Comment: The question in the OP is not using pandas, so this does not answer the question